# SQL Server: Summary of amount for year and week number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that yields Year, Iso week and sum of amount for that year and week.

My problem is that the way I am doing it returns the amount for the first days of 2021 as being from week 53 when it actually should of course be a part of week 53 of the year 2020.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  datepart(year, [MyDate]) AS [Year],
  datepart(iso_week,[MyDate]) AS WeekNumber,
  sum([Amount]) AS TotalAmount
FROM [Temp].[dbo].[MyTable]
GROUP BY datepart(year, [MyDate]), datepart(iso_week,[MyDate])
ORDER BY datepart(year, [MyDate]), datepart(iso_week,[MyDate])
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: *"My problem is that the way I am doing it returns the amount for the first days of 2021 as being from week 53."* That's what ISO Weeks do though, it's intentional. Week 1, using ISO Week numbering, is the first week with a Thursday in it. [ISO Week Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

Comment: Also, I suggest avoiding single quotes (`'`) for delimit identifying aliases. Single quotes are  for literal strings, and using them for aliases can be quite confusing. Especially when they *only* work for defining the alias. `ORDER BY 'Year'` would *not* order by the column aliased using `AS 'Year'`.

Comment: "_A calendar week is identified within a calendar year by the calendar week number. This is its ordinal position within the year, applying the rule that the first calendar week of a year is the one that includes the first Thursday of that year and that the last calendar week of a calendar year is the week immediately preceding the first calendar week of the next calendar year._" ISO 8601

Comment: 1. comment: Right - I understand that but is just do not know how to get the the desired result.
2. comment - I have removed the single quotes that I usually do not used. Here I was just thinking about YEAR being a reserved word but I can put it in brackets as I have now done.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by doing this:

```
SELECT 
dbo.GetIsoYear(MyDate) AS [Year],
datepart(iso_week,MyDate) AS WeekNumber,
sum(Amount) AS 'TotalAmount'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY dbo.GetIsoYear(MyDate), datepart(iso_week,MyDate)
ORDER BY dbo.GetIsoYear(MyDate), datepart(iso_week,MyDate)
```

and here is the function I am using:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIsoYear](@Date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ResultVar int
  DECLARE @IsoWeek int
  DECLARE @Month int

  SELECT @IsoWeek = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,@Date)
  SELECT @Month = DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)

  IF @IsoWeek = 53 AND @Month = 1
    SET @ResultVar = YEAR(@Date) - 1
  ELSE
    SET @ResultVar = YEAR(@Date)

  RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

I do not know if using a function here has performance issues but I would think that it should run rather fast.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, SQL Server offers `iso_week` as an argument to `datepart()`, but not `iso_year`.  Some perusing on the web [suggests this code](https://capens.net/content/sql-year-iso-week):

```
SELECT v.iso_year, v.iso_week,
       sum([Amount]) AS TotalAmount
FROM [Temp].[dbo].[MyTable] t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t.mydate), 1, 1)), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(t.mydate), 1, 1))),
             datepart(iso_week, t.[MyDate])
            )
     ) v(iso_year, iso_week)
GROUP BY iso_year, iso_week
ORDER BY iso_year, iso_week
```

Comment: This query returns the right year and week for last days of 2020 and first days of 2021. The year is wrong though for everything with a date later than that. (2020).